# why the query is slow when I do not use the sub partition on in memory db?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, in-memory-database

I use oracle in memory db and I create a table that partition with date column,and the table has sub partition(hash) on customerid based on 64 pieces.

When I just use date partition not sub partition on select that table the query is too slow? Why it was like that?

thanks in advance

Comment: This really is not enough information for us to go on.

Comment: Can you provide a SQL Monitor report